# Control+click does not open pages in a new tab

Tags: bug, user-interface, new-nav, navigation

On this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/haskell?show=all&sort=newest, control+clicking the new, popular and need answers tabs opens the pages in the same tab instead of in a new tab. In the past this problem did not exist.

Comment: In Chrome, right click does work.

Comment: This is due to new navigation, you can opt out while it is still in beta. (hence naturally got lots of bugs)

Comment: @PatrickHofman when you say "right click does work" you mean to say "right click and open in a new tab"? is that correct?

Comment: @HackerKarma indeed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard what OS are you on?

Comment: @HackerKarma not releavt, I am on the old nav so getting Page Not Found for the link.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ohh... I thought you with such high-reps probably joined this experiment...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't know you could opt out of this abomination! Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @HackerKarma I did and soon left due to too many critical bugs which caused it to become a pain to use the site.

Comment: @rightfold lol cheers!

Comment: @ShadowWizard and all -- "user-interface" tag is added because this falls under "navigational tabs"-- Refer: http://www.usability.gov/what-and-why/user-interface-design.html

Comment: @HackerKarma sorry, not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @ShadowWizard "clicking on navigation tabs/tags" is also a part of UI. I added the flag "user-interface" to this post.

Comment: @Hack oh sorry, approved now

Comment: @PatrickHofman Or even better "wheel-click".

Comment: My middle click button is broken. :v

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has something to do with the way current Stack Overflow's on-page on-click activity is handled under the new-nav. As pointed out by ShadowWizard in the comment:

> This is due to new navigation, you can opt out while it is still in
>   beta. (hence naturally got lots of bugs)

Yes, this behavior is due to the recent changes (this problem did not exist when I was on the old nav) made in the new-nav where the AJAX (as per Patrick Hofman's comment below) call handles on-click (ctrl-click or cmd-click in case of Mac) on the tab links to open in.

Unfortunately, I am on Mac OS so here is what I did. I installed a "**[Command-Click Fix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/command-click-fix/leklllfdadjjglhllebogdjfdipdjhhp?hl=en)**" Chrome extension. This extension makes Command-Click open a new tab on pages that don't do it properly. Make sure to reload/refresh the webpage after installing the extension. Now, using *cmd+click* on the tab links works perfectly i.e. opens the link in a new browser tab.

**P.S.**

The above test was performed in the Chrome Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit). I can reproduce this on the other two browsers i.e. Firefox (Version 39.0) and Safari (Version 8.0.7 (10600.7.12))

I am using MacBook Pro (Retina, Late 2013; OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.2).

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks. I changed it to AJAX call.

Comment: In any case, wheel-click should do perfectly, even on the new nav.

Comment: @MouseEvent I did't notice but ur username "mouse event" is relevant... :) yes, if I do mouse right-click and open tab or any other wheel-click alike working fine.... BUT it's the "keyboard key + mouse click combo" has the issue and that what OP is asking here.